# SAP Adobe Livecycle Designer PDF import crash

Tags: pdf, adobe, sap-gui, livecycle-designer

I am trying to import a PDF into SAP Logon using Adobe Livecycle Designer.
Every time I try it, my SAP Logon freezes and I have to login again.

There is no error message or anything that could give a clue.

I made the PDF super simple, with only a few lines of text.
I am using a plane Interface which is activated and a plane Form.
I have no access to the server so I can't look for Protocols.
What could cause the freezing and what can I do about it?

I have tried this with only the Adobe Livecycle Designer again.

Exact Steps:

1. open ALD.
2. File->open.
3. choose my PDF with only text.

-> ALD shuts down.

I already reinstalled ALD.
I already restarted my PC.

Comment: `I am trying to import a PDF into SAP using adobe livecycle designer` how do you do that? Give the exact steps

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Adobe Livecycle Designer 11.0

You have to install patch level 7 for Adobe Livecycle Designer 11.0 SAP

You can find the download in the SAP Portal, search for this Note: 2692497

But you have to have a SUSER login to do so.

> **2018/09/13** IFbA: Adobe LiveCycle Designer 11.0 crashes during importing/opening Print PDF, Hinweis 2692497